# Kinect not grabbing image in VMWare Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: ubuntu, kinect, vmware

I have installed Ubuntu-13.04 in vmware with windows8 as host. The system does not show any error message like "Device not connected" or anything else,still kinect is not grabbing any image.The panel just shows 3-axis line.

I tried zooming in and out but in vain.

Any Help?